# Fancybox OK with Firefox but zero with IE8 (code attached)

Tags: fancybox

I am a new user to fancybox 2.0 and have to been able to get it to work. After a couple of days trying, I eventually stripped down test page do the bare bones. It works with Firefox but not with IE8.

Please, can someone look at this code and see where I am going wrong.

http://www.bytebrothers.com/bb_tester/Video_lightbox_test.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your document has not `DOCTYPE` so IE switches to quirks mode.

Fancybox needs standards mode to run properly so set a valid `DOCTYPE`. You can check http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/ or simply set `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Hello @JFK, thanks for your reply. Although I cannot manage to have fancybox-2 work with PDFs => [Click here for the simple question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385496/fancybox-2-not-showing-pdf-in-ie-8)