# Fancybox-2 not showing PDF in IE-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, fancybox, fancybox-2

Can't get Fancybox-2 to show PDFs with Internet Explorer!
(It works fine in Chrome and Firefox)

In `<head>` I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            height: '100%',
            // width: '50%',
            //openEffect  : 'none',
            // closeEffect : 'none',
            iframe: {
                preload: false
            },
            afterShow: function () {
                $(".fancybox-wrap").draggable();
            },
            beforeLoad: function () {
                this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

then in `<body>` I have:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" caption="my test" href="PDF/test.pdf" target="_blank" title="test PDF"><img style="border:0;" src="../img/pdficon.png "></a>
```

How can I get it to work, in your opinion?

Comment: does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/SQSFp/show/ Also check that you have a proper DOCTYPE

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply @JFK. Your fiddle results in opening Acrobat Reader. in IE-8 I only get [this empty modal window](http://i.imgur.com/v1LfN7e.png) PS: I use <!DOCTYPE>

Comment: [This other link](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_16Jan12.html) of yours is not working either, unfortunately.

Comment: Check this article that describes your issue http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-view-pdf-web.html

Comment: For me, this is a localized issue with your own IE8 adobe reader plugin. It could also be IE's compatibility view mode (try turn it on/off)